# How to give access to a DynamoDB table?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-iam

In IAM I tried creating the following policy for a user (account id in arn obfuscated):

```
{
 "Version": "2012-10-17",
 "Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "dynamodb:*",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-west-2:999999999999:table/busUsers"
    }
 ]
}
```

However, it resulted in:

> This policy defines some actions, resources, or conditions that do not provide permissions. To grant access, policies must have an action that has an applicable resource or condition. For details, choose Show remaining [Learn more](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/troubleshoot_policies.html?icmpid=docs_iam_console#policy-summary-not-grant-permissions)

`Show remaining` shows:

> One or more actions do not have an applicable resource.

I looked up the [Learn more](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/troubleshoot_policies.html?icmpid=docs_iam_console#policy-summary-not-grant-permissions) link and it says to replace the arn in the `Resource` element with `*`. I am confused now. What does `*` mean? I want to grant access to a specific DynamoDB table of mine. How do I specify that?

---

EDIT: I removed all DyanamoDB actions and just selected one `GetItem` and it's:
[image]

When I deselect `GetItem`, both error messages go away.
When I select **table** Any, the first error message goes away.
When I select **Resource** Any, the second error message goes away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its because you are granting permissions for all dynamodb actions to a table resource, but not all of those actions are actually applicable to a table.

For example dynamodb:DescribeStream is not applicable to a table, only to a Stream, but your are granting permission to this resource anyway.

You can safely ignore this warning.

EDIT: You may not have realised you can just click Save Policy and it will work fine.

EDIT: Thanks for posting your screenshot. There are no errors here, just warnings, which might be better called tips in this case.

When you enter the ARN of a resource manually, AWS does not appear to recognise what type of resource it is (i.e. a table). If you add the resource through the table ARN generator, you wont any warnings. In either case you end up with the same policy.

Comment: Instead of selecting all actions (*), I tried selecting one by one. However, every single one I selected, eg `GetItem`, resulted in `One or more actions may not support this resource.`  My resource field value is as in my original question. (The warning does not appear if I do not use the specific resource arn but use Any resource of type=table.)  Doesn't my resource arn specify a DynamoDB table and of which `GetItem` should be supported?

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of the visual editor and the json of the policy?

Comment: added.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could you please explain more of what you mean by "enter the ARN of a resource manually" vs "add the resource through the table ARN generator" - I'm not quite sure what you mean by either one.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that you are running into a bug [discussed by Amazon employee rob@AWS] of the IAM Policy Visual editor itself (and therefore not experiencing any actual problem):
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=282453

When I alleviated my personal problem (which had me looking at this Question in the first place), my similar warnings still persisted (even after my problem was solved by something else) - that leads me to believe my similar experience per the Visual editor may have indeed been that bug (and not causing/involved in my prior problem at all).